# Connect Timeout for REST client

Tags: python, requests

I have REST client which uses python requests library for REST calls. What are the parameters need to be accounted to set connect timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check at the website [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts)

When you try to browse a website, you can specify the timeout value directly:

```
requests.get('http://github.com', timeout={timeout_value} )
```

Comment: Let me explain my question. I am looking for suggestion on the number of seconds or minutes  which need to be used as timeout_value and not how to use the API.

Comment: However long you (your users, your processes) are willing to wait before considering the request a failure, after taking into account how long the request takes under normal circumstances.

Comment: @HBruijn FOr my application, it will be OK to have read timeout for larger value like 30 secconds, but for connect timeout I haven't done any profiling, I wanted to have sense how long its OK to wait before declaring a connection is timeout. Is there any RFC guidelines or standard ?